# padding and margin for CSS <li> simply NOT WORKING

Tags: css, inheritance, padding, margin

I am working on this site, and I have a pretty large .css document.  For some reason I cant get these list items to have a padding or margin of anything other than 0px.

I have no idea where it might be inheriting this from, and why me writing

```
{
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
}
```

does nothing!

Here is the [site](http://wiffle.info), im referring to the element in a really ugly, bright green, with the class of ".wiffleMainNav ul li."

The CSS rule is at the bottom of the linked styles sheet.

Thanks so much!

-Aza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of the padding line:

```
padding: 5px,
margin: 0px 2px;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a comma in your definition.

**Change this**

```
.wiffleMainNav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px, /* PROBLEM! :) */
    margin: 0px 2px;
    background: green;
}
```

**To this**

```
.wiffleMainNav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px; /* FIXED */
    margin: 0px 2px;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css uses this:

.wiffleMainNav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px,
    margin: 0px 2px;
    background: green;
}

Note the Comma after "padding: 5px" instead of semi-colon.

Comment: wow, thanks so much. needless to say I am slightly embarrassed. but hey, i definitely appreciate your help, next time i will definitely check for the rogue comma!